# How to Replace All Formula In Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am Want To Replace All Formula (Example : =Sheets3!A1 To =Sheets3!A2... Also =Sheets3!B1 to =Sheets3!B2) [image: And This is My Screenshot]

I would like to use this (Find & Replace)

I tried (Find & Replace) To Replace ALl Formulas.But Didn't Solved

Answer (score 1):

your <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> window should look like:

[image]